# How to get ajax result in php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to get the ajax result on a php variable. Please help me out.

```
 <select name="type" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
      <option value="">---SELECT ITEM TYPE---</option>
      <option value="Food">Food</option>
      <option value="Beverage">Beverage</option>
    </select>
```

Ajax Code

```
<script>
function showCustomer(str) {
    var xmlhttp;    
    if (str === "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","itemtype.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

itemtype.php

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['q'] ?>
```

Now i want to get result in php variable for eg:-

```
<?php $iamvariable="<div id='txtHint'></div>"; echo $iamvariable ?>
```

I want to get the result from ajax into `$iamvariable` and i don't know how to get it i just tried with above code and i couldn't get it. Is their any way to get it?

Comment: please format this properly

Comment: why you want to use ajax then? If you want to get result in php use curl or file get contents....

Comment: @Dagon i have tried to manage it properly hope it is ok now.

Comment: @Vickrant i have a long form and it is just one part and previously i used javascript code and their was problem of reloading so now i want to ajax to implement it.

Comment: Not getting a clear picture of what you exactly want. Please elaborate. I am still confussed

Comment: @Dagon I took the liberty to submit an edit request.

Comment: @Bibek Brackets always go on the right side in javascript. It can be a syntax error not to. In general you put space operator space for things like  = or + or == third js you almost always mean === instead of == three ='s disables auto type coercion.

Comment: @Vickrant i have a long form and it is just single part of code. I used javascript to pass value from url and get in php file but the problem was it reload when it pass value. So, now i want to ajax to pass value and to get value in php file.

Comment: While this may not have place in the question, you may also want to consider jQuery. It will make your code more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :-

```
<select name="type" id="type">
      <option value="">---SELECT ITEM TYPE---</option>
      <option value="Food">Food</option>
      <option value="Beverage">Beverage</option>
    </select>
   <div id='txtHint'></div>
```

this line include in header :-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

write this script in page :-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#type").on("change",function(){
        var data = $("#type").val();
        $.ajax({url: "itemtype.php",data:{type: data},
     type: 'post', success: function(result){
            $("#txtHint").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

itemtype.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['type']; ?>
```

Comment: how can i show this result in input type ie<input type="text" id="txtHint">

Comment: @Bibek to put the request content in an `<input />` field use the jquery `val()` method: `$("#txtHint").val(result);` instead of `$("#txtHint").html(result);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the result from ajax call and assign it to , instead of the following line,

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

try this:

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

innerHtml specifies the html content of the element. value sets the value of the input element.

Another way using jQuery:

```
$("#txtHint").val(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Comment: Thank Beno for answer but i am using code which mukesh prajapat have given me above and i know that i have to use something on .html(result) but i am not being able to find it. Could you please help me?

Comment: @Bibek: Added the answer in the edit. Hope this mets your need.